# SSRS Security settings using ReportService2010 - .GetPolicies InheritParent value

Tags: sql-server, powershell, reporting-services

I need to check and add permissions on lots of folders, I was looking into using ReportService2010, but I have doubt regarding inheritance of security settings. In all examples I found online they are using:

```
$inheritParent = $true
```

in method

```
.GetPolicies($reportFolder, [ref]$inheritParent)
```

but this is not always the case.. sometimes folders have security setting independent from parent. Is there a way to check this setting using same assembly?

I have some doubts what exactly this does, I ran the same with $false and results were the same. Still I'd like to avoid breaking something when adding new user to folder.

I checked GetProperties and GetPermissions methods, but they do not return value I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

$inheritParent has to be initialized before it can be used with .GetPolicies. As you've already discovered, it doesn't matter what value you use. You can even set it to $null if you like, which might make it less confusing. You'll want to check the value after the call is made to determine if the policies returned are inherited or not.

The code found at https://github.com/microsoft/ReportingServicesTools might be useful to you. You can use it in its entirety or just as a reference.